# Missing artifact 8.1.2-SNAPSHOT. Can't fully install docx4j

Tags: java, maven, docx4j

I'm trying to install docx4j on eclipse but every time I try and install it I get these errors. I'm doing it by the tutorial from this [website](https://www.docx4java.org/blog/2015/06/docx4j-from-github-in-eclipse-5-years-on/)

Can someone help me out?

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Missing artifact
>   org.docx4j:docx4j-core:jar:8.1.2-SNAPSHOT pom.xml /docx4j-JAXB-MOXy   line
>   49    Maven Dependency Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Missing artifact
>   org.docx4j:docx4j-core:jar:8.1.2-SNAPSHOT pom.xml /docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl  line
>   55    Maven Dependency Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The project was not built
>   since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for
>   java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this
>   project   docx4j-JAXB-MOXy        Unknown Java Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The project was not built
>   since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for
>   java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this
>   project   docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl       Unknown Java Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The type java.lang.Object
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files NamespacePrefixMapper.java  /docx4j-JAXB-MOXy/src/main/java/org/docx4j/jaxb/moxy    line
>   1 Java Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The type java.lang.Object
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files NamespacePrefixMapper.java  /docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl/src/main/java/org/docx4j/jaxb/ri line
>   1 Java Problem

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using docx4j from Maven central, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589317/1031689  You should use one and only one of the docx4j-JAXB-* deps (but it looks like you have docx4j-JAXB-MOXy and docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl).

The docx4j-JAXB-* deps on Maven central do not point at -SNAPSHOT jars.

The source code on GitHub does use -SNAPSHOT versions, so if you have cloned that, first run mvn install to install the SNAPSHOT jars in your local .m2 maven repo.  Then Eclipse ought to be happy. You might need to rebuild in Eclipse and/or do "maven update" on the project in Eclipse first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I fixed my problem and I'm really sorry for crossposting, I was just trying to get an answer from anywhere.